# How to root "Infocus M2" (smartphone on sale at snapdeal from March 2015 in India) so that pre-installed apps can be removed?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, uninstallation, bloatware

Infocus M2 is on sale at snapdealdotcom. Its specifications are as below:

```
4.2-inch (1280 × 768 pixels) 355PPI LTPS display
Android v4.4 (KitKat) OS
1.3 GHz quad-core MediaTek MT6582 processor
Mali-400 MP2 (500 MHz) GPU
1GB RAM, 8GB internal memory, Expandable memory up to 64GB with micro SD
8MP Auto Focus Camera with LED flash, f/2.2 aperture, 5P lenses
8MP front-facing auto-focus camera with LED flash, f/2.2 aperture
Dual micro SIMs
3.5mm audio jack, FM Radio
3G, Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n, Bluetooth 4.0 + BLE and GPS
2010 mAh non-removable battery
```

Would appreaciate help on rooting this mobile. Thankyou

Comment: Querying Google with *How to root Infocus M2* results in this link at first page http://www.androidrootguide.com/2015/04/how-to-root-infocus-m2-and-install-custom-recovery.html I can post the content as an answer but that's not worth if the guide fails to root your device (if followed properly), not to mention that would be just copy-paste and nothing else. Try it and post ([edit]) the results.

Comment: Since its a MT6582 processor, **SP Flash Tools** and **MTK Droid Tools** can also help. Google them for their latest version and support for your device's chip. These tools are  well known amongst Mediatek users for their  capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all you've to do is install USB drivers and use iRoot software to root your Infocus M2.

Be aware that this will void your warranty.